# Unknown SSL error while websocket connect in Java 17 and Android 10+

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, ssl, websocket

My Android application cannot establish a secure websocket connection with the server after upgrading the Java version from 8 to 17. Now on API version 30+ I always get same error:

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection to [wss://192.168.0.213:8080/input] failed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:480)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:185)
at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient.lambda$doHandshakeInternal$0$org-springframework-web-socket-client-standard-StandardWebSocketClient(StandardWebSocketClient.java:151)
at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.call(Unknown Source:10)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Bytes were consumed from the input during a write
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WrapperFuture.get(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:518)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:329)
.. 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Bytes were consumed from the input during a write
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WebSocketSslHandshakeThread.checkResult(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:440)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WebSocketSslHandshakeThread.run(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:381)
```

This is how i use it:

```
Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", BouncyCastleProvider())
val keyFile = ComponentProvider.instance.keyFile
keyStore.load(keyFile, KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray())

val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray())
val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore)

val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.keyManagers, trustManagerFactory.trustManagers, null)

val container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer()
val webSocketClient = StandardWebSocketClient(container)
webSocketClient.userProperties = mapOf(Pair("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_CONTEXT", sslContext))


val converter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
converter.objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder().addModule(JavaTimeModule()).build()

val webSocketStompClient = WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient)

Thread{
   webSocketStompClient.connect(ComponentProvider.instance.baseUrl, sessionHandler)
}.start()
```

`keyFile` is keystore in p12 format and `baseUrl` is server adress.

App settings:

```
compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
```

And dependency for this part of app (not everything):

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.9.20'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:2.7.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-messaging:6.0.13'

}
```

I changed the server certificate, self-signed it, used the legacy method, but the result was the same.

I noticed that replacing KeyManagerFactory with null or using a known bad KeyStore does not change the result.

I tried to use `networkSecurityConfig` and put cert+key in der format in files

```
<domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.213</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/mydercert"

                />
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
```

Everything works fine on desktop with same keystore and codes

UPD:
The connection is always established after three attempts. What I see with Wireshark:
[wireshark log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXNdz.png)

Somehow client hello contains TLSv1.0 [client hello](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHaFC.png), and error occurs after server send "change cipher spec". But the third time the client answers to server with "change cipher spec" and they connect.